# Install ruby gem in rescue block when 'LoadError' occurs

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install a ruby gem from a ruby script when it can't load the required gem from local system. Here is my code.

```
begin
  require '<gem name here>'
rescue LoadError
  puts `gem install <gem name here>`
  require '<gem name here>'
end
```

The code above installs the gem in the `rescue` block. But when it requires the gem, it shows this error:

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
:55:in require': cannot load such file -- <gem name here> (LoadError)
```

How can this be solved? I want the gem to be loaded within the `rescue` block if not already present in the system.

Comment: Don't you know the complete list of gems required at the beginning?

Comment: Are you literally writing `'<gem name here>'` in the code?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I know complete list of the gems. For production systems, If we write like this we don't have to do any manual installation of gems. For that purpose I was doing like this.

Comment: @sawa nope. actually I was installing jira-ruby gem. But for generic purpose, I mentioned it like that.

Comment: I think you have to reload some ruby environment stuff to get the gem list read in new (kindof, tenderlove knows that stuff better ;) ). Would shipping the gem with your script be the better solution?

Comment: @Felix Its kind of have to do like that situation for me. so if there is any other alternative to install gem, please let me know.

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy Of course. I dont know how you call your ruby script, but you can download a .gem-file (or the folder) and make your ruby understand that it should use it (e.g. `ruby -I/my/gem/folder`). Read up on rubygems and your ruby interpreter.

Comment: @Felix I appreciate your help. But I want to done it in the script and require at the same time. Is that possible? Is my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rigorous searching, I found an answer. If we use `Gem.clear_paths` after installing the gem, it will now available to the script. Total updated code is :

```
begin
require '<gem name here>'
rescue LoadError
  puts `gem install <gem name here>`
  Gem.clear_paths
  require '<gem name here>'
end
```

Comment: Bless you for coming back and answering your question.